# How to get Firestore document ID marshalled into struct?

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch a document from Firestore and have it marshalled into my custom struct. Currently all data is unmarshalled, but I can't find a way to get the document ID into my struct. Here is an example:

```
type MyStruct struct {
    ID    string                        // What to put here?
    PropA string `firestore:"prop_a"`
    PropB string `firestore:"prop_b"`
}

doc, err := client.Doc(docref).Get(ctx) // Fetch document
var x MyStruct                          // Allocate object
err = doc.DataTo(&x)                    // Unmarshal
```

The result is that `PropA` and `PropB` are populated on `x`, but I have no idea how to populate the ID field with the document ID.

I can obviously just manually fish it out of `doc`, but it feels like `DataTo` should be able to handle this.

Comment: This is a reasonable feature request, since there is equivalent functionality for JVM languages. You can file it with Firebase support: https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1):

The id is not part of the document data. Assign it as you mentioned:

```
x.ID = doc.Ref.ID
```

Comment: In Swift it's possible to annotate a field with `@DocumentID` and have it populated, no such thing in Go?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same in Unity3D (C#). Do you know if it's possible?